# Send python request to .net API

Tags: python, json, .net, api

I'm trying to send post request from python to .net Core Api. But im receiving

```
The JSON value could not be converted to NetflowInputViewModel.
```

My view model is =

```
public class NetflowInputViewModel
    {
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public int ipv6 { get; set; }
    }
```

And my controller is =

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("CdrDetails")]
        public JsonResult CdrDetails([FromBody] NetflowInputViewModel model)
        {
            List<NetflowOutputViewModel> netFlow = netflowCdrService.GetDetails(model.startDate, model.endDate, model.ipv6);
            if (netFlow == default)
            {
                return new JsonResult("No Records.");
            }
            else
                return new JsonResult(netFlow);
        }
```

I'm trying to send with parameters from python like this =

```
import json
from datetime import date, datetime
import requests

def json_serial(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        return obj.isoformat()
    raise TypeError("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))

url = "https://localhost:44388/api/NetflowCdr/CdrDetails"

start_date = datetime(2021, 11, 29, 15, 10, 0)
end_date = datetime(2021, 11, 29, 15, 20, 0)
myobj = {"startDate": start_date, "endDate": end_date, "ipv6": 0}
aa = json.dumps(myobj, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
x = requests.post(url, json=aa, verify=False, headers={
    "Content-Type":"application/json", "Accept": "*/*"
})
print(x.text)
```

How can i handle it? I guess i should change somethings at .net core side but i don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this help but I think this can help you
in .net core 3.0 Newtonsoft.JSON package so you can try this

```
Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package
```

In your startup.cs add

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

This might can help you.